# why if I want to create a rayleigh fading channel with $E[|H_{i,j}|^2]$,I should multiply $\sqrt{\frac{1}{N_R \times N_T}}$?

Tags: digital-communications, fading-channel

I want to create a rayleigh fading channel,and my classmate told me that I can create an $N_R \times N_T $ channel $\mathbf H$ with $E[|H_{i,j}|^2]$,that is,$\sqrt{\frac{1}{N_R \times N_T}}\times CN(0,1)$.

Does anyone know why if I want to create a rayleigh fading channel with $E[|H_{i,j}|^2]$,I should multiply $\sqrt{\frac{1}{N_R \times N_T}}$?,how is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{N_R \times N_T}}$  calculated?

$N_R$ is the number of received antennas,and $N_T$ is the number of transmitted antennas

Comment: What does your classmate say about the matter?

Comment: he didn't say why,so I ask here

Comment: @DilipSarwate he said that $\sqrt{\frac{1}{N_R \times N_T}}$ is normalizing,just like the $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$ in the CN(0,1),but i don't know how to calculate to the $\sqrt{\frac{1}{N_R \times N_T}}$